# Sending email from other account

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I send emails through Outlook using Excel VBA. I am using my work computer with my work email as the main account, but want to send from another account that is logged in.

I have not managed to integrate any of the code found online.

The below code is without my attempt of fixing it.

```vb
Sub Test1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strbody As String
    For Each cell In Range("D2:D2")
        strbody = strbody & cell.Value & vbNewLine
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "A personal message from the founder"
                .Body = "Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strbody
                .Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways in Outlook:

1. If another account is configured in Outlook you need to use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent.

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
 If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
 Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
 End If 
 
 Next  
End Sub
```

2. If you have got permissions set by the Exchange admin to send on behalf of another person you need to use the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which returns a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

Comment: The first suggestions seems to work - thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! It makes sense to mark the answer then so other readers could find a solution easier.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean send from another email address? If so just add :

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Email@Other.com" 'Change to the email address you want to send from
```

e.g

```
With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Email@Other.com"
            .Subject = "A personal message from the founder"
            .Body = "Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strbody
            .Send
        End With
```

Comment: I  tried this, but believe I need permission to send on behalf of which I am not sure I can/want to do outside of my organisation. I think Eugene's answer below works, but thanks for helping!