Send e-mail via specified e-mail address
My macro should send the e-mails via another e-mail address.
The e-mail address has been set up and is stored in Outlook.
I can view it in the account settings.
I set this e-mail address as the default, but the e-mail is still sent via my normal e-mail address.
I have not attached the part where the mail is compiled with the information from a table.
How can I ensure this e-mail is sent from the second mail address?
Sub Mails()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1") 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim i As Long
 
    Dim otherAccount As Object
    For Each acc In outlookApp.Session.Accounts
        If acc.DisplayName = example@company.com Then 
            Set otherAccount = acc
            Exit For
        End If
    Next acc
 
    If otherAccount Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(i, "E").Value) Then
            Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With mailItem
                .SendUsingAccount = otherAccount
                .To = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                ' .CC = ' optional
                .Subject = "Reminder" & ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
                .HTMLBody = ""

                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next i
 
    Set mailItem = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set otherAccount = Nothing
End Sub

Set .SendUsingAccount = otherAccount did not work.

Not tested it but this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774386/sending-email-from-other-account suggests you need Set .SendUsingAccount = otherAccount

but unfortunately this does not work

What kind off accountant is it? Exchange or POP3/SMTP?

I don't know, it's a normal Outlook address

I use a function able to set/extract the other account. Of course, the respective account must be configured on Outlook. My example works as an automation from Excel. Otherwise, OLook should be Outlook Application :
Function GetAccountOf(sEmailAddress As String, ByRef OLook As Object) As Object
  Dim oAccount As Object
  Set GetAccountOf = Nothing
  For Each oAccount In OLook.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount = sEmailAddress Then
      Set GetAccountOf = oAccount
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next oAccount
End Function

It should be called in the next way:
Sub SendUsingDifferentAccount()
 Dim OLook As New Outlook.Application
 Dim acc As Outlook.Account
 Dim Mitem As Outlook.MailItem
 
 Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)
    
   
    Set acc = GetAccountOf("theotherAccount@xxx.com", OLook)
    If acc Is Nothing Then MsgBox "The respective account is not recognized...": Exit Sub
    If acc.DisplayName = "theotherAccount@xxx.com" Then
        With Mitem
               
            .To = "..."
            .cc = "..."
            .BCC = "..."
         
            Set .SendUsingAccount = acc
         
            .Send
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Edited:
Please, copy only the first Sub I posted and try using the next adapted code:
Sub Mails()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1") 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim i As Long
 
    Dim otherAccount As Object
    Set otherAccount = GetAccountOf("example@company.com", outlookApp)
    If otherAccount Is Nothing Then MsgBox "The respective account is not recognized...": Exit Sub
 
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(i, "E").Value) Then
            Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With mailItem
                Set .SendUsingAccount = otherAccount
                .To = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                ' .CC = ' optional
                .Subject = "Reminder" & ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
                .HTMLBody = "Test"

                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next i
 
    Set mailItem = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set otherAccount = Nothing
End Sub

Not tested, but adapted in this way it should work (I think...)

Thank you! Unfortunately I'm still a beginner, so I don't know exactly how to use it in my code

@jaayjoo Please, see the adapted code I posted after Edited.

Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The macro can be executed, but I do not receive an e-mail.

@jaayjoo place Debug.print .otherAccount.DisplyName, ws.Cells(i, "F").Value: Stop above  For i = 1 To lastRow code line. What does it return in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE) when code stops on this line?

I only get an error message because of the new line: Error compiling: Invalid or insufficient defined reference

@jaayjoo I typed by mistake a dot in front of otherAccount. It must be Debug.print otherAccount.DisplyName, ws.Cells(i, "F").Value: Stop.

I get the error message:Runtime error '1004': Application or object-defined error

@jaayjoo After the mentioned error, is the suggested code line highlighted? If so, this only means that you inserted it in a wrong place. It must be inserted just above For i = 1 To lastRow, as I said... If not, which code line is highlighted? Without showing it, only mentioning the error does not mean too much in order to understand the error...

It is inserted in the right place. No line is highlighted. I only get the following error: Runtime error 1004: Application or object-defined error. When I start the macro from the Excel file, I get the following error: 400.

@jaayjoo Do you have AnyDesk installed (on your computer, even not installed)? If so, if not something confidential I can remotely enter your computer and see what is it about. You can send the application ID on my personal mail account (from my profile). But, announce me here about that. Otherwise, your mail may go to spam and I usually do not check my mail very frequent...

Unfortunately, it was not possible to send mails with the group mailbox because it was also under my e-mail accounts. Now the group mailbox is out of the settings (e-mail accounts) and you can send mails manually. But the macro cannot find the address now

@jaayjoo I am afraid I cannot get you... Did the error message disappear? What about remote connection? Isn't it allowed? Aren't you interested in such a way? You did not say anything on this issue.

Unfortunately, screen transmission is not allowed, so I can't do that ...
The only error message I get is the following: “The respective account is not recognized...”

@jaayjoo So, you placed the debugging code line in the correct position and the code does not reach it, anymore... That it is not an error message, it is a message sent by the code in case of not finding any account i  OLook.Session.Accounts with the searched mail address... Maybe, you misspelled it, or it is of a type which not includes it in Session.Accounts.

No, the e-mail address has been entered correctly. I can also see in the Outlook settings under the other settings that this mailbox is stored with me. I can also send mails from it manually, but unfortunately this does not work via VBA ...

@Faneduru isn't the problem with DisplyName? Should be DisplayName
